# MVC 3/4 SiteMap Provider exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MVC SiteMap from codeplex , I've set sitemap to this

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="LEADS" controller="Leads" action="DetailsLeads"   Url="/Leads/DetailsLeads" roles="TEST">
          <mvcSiteMapNode title="LEADS1" controller="Leads" action="ScheduleMettingLeads"   Url="/Leads/ScheduleMettingLeads" roles="TEST"/>
          <mvcSiteMapNode title="LEADS2" controller="Leads" action="ServiceAppealLeads"  Url="/Leads/ServiceAppealLeads" roles="TEST"/>
        </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

When I am setting securityTrimmingEnabled="true" , I am getting following Error:

**Ambiguous controller. Found multiple controller types for LeadsController. Consider narrowing the places to search by adding you controller namespaces to ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.**

Comment: do you have multiple controllers named `Leads` in different areas?

Comment: its the same controller with different actions

Comment: that's not what i asked. Do you have `Foo.Controllers.Leads` and `Foo.Areas.Bar.Controllers.Leads`?

Answer (score 0):

Area setup is quite tricky. Please see this issue for an explanation of how to set up areas with MvcSiteMapProvider.

https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/78?source=cc#issuecomment-20918916